# Why .NET ASMX web service on secure.site.com can't be called from www.site.com?

Tags: asmx

We have a web service on https://secure.site.com/service.asmx it works fine from https://secure.site.com/consumer.html

but when we try to use it from https://www.site.com/consumer.html we can't do it. Getting 403 error.

I'ts probably something related to webservice security (because of different subdomains) but I can't figure out what. 
How to make https://secure.site.com/service.asmx be accessible from https://www.site.com/consumer.html?

Update:
Calling webserivce using JQuery Ajax.

```
  $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "https://secure.site.com/service.asmx/method",
        data: {},
        dataType: "xml",
        success: method_result,
        error: AjaxFailed
    })
```

;

Thanks.

Comment: How are you calling it?  is it an AJAX call to the service?

Comment: It's AJAX call to the service.

Comment: It probably doesn't work because they're two unrelated domains. The domain match algorithm doesn't care that they have the same base domain in common.

Comment: Yep, looks like that, but how to make it work? Is there any configuration for that?

Comment: The two domains are not related. That's how the Internet works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recall working on something like this. I just made a demo app and recall having to add something like the following in one of the htlm pages within a javascript block:

document.domain: "*.site.com"; or "site.com";

details are fuzzy and it maybe for another issues I had, but its something to go on.